# javascript regexp to identify different components of a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a very specific requirement. Consider the sentence "I am a robot X-rrt, I am 35 and my creator is 5-MAF. Everything here is 5 times than my world5 - hurray"

I am interested in a regexp which recognizes "I", "am", "a" , "robot", "X-rrt", ",", "I", "am", "35", "and", "my", "creator", "is", "5-MAF", ".", "Everthing", "here", "is", "5", "times", "than", "my", "world5", "-", "hurray"

i.e 1)it should recognize all punctuations except "-" when it a part of a word
2)numbers if part of a word containg alphabets should not be recognized seperately

I am extremely confused with this one. Would appreciate some advise!

Comment: Please define exactly, when is a punctuation part of a word.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting at each group of whitespaces, and before dots and commas:

```js
str.split(/\s+|(?=[.,])/);
```

Comment: Didn't know that `.split` can receive regexp - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this match regexp:

str.match(/[\w\d-]+|.|,/g);

Answer (score 0):

This is not too easy. I suggest some preprocession on the text before a split, for example:

```js
var text = "I am a robot X-rrt, I am 35 and my creator is 5-MAF. Everything here is 5 times than my world5 - hurray";
var preprocessedText = text.replace(/(\w|^)(\W)( |$)/g, "$1 $2$3");
var tokens = preprocessedText.split(" ");
alert(tokens.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in perl. Shouldn't be too hard to translate to javascript.

```
my $sentence = 'I am a robot X-rrt, I am 35 and my creator is 5-MAF. Everything here is 5 times than my world5 - hurray';

my @words = split(/\s|(?<!-)\b(?!-)/, $sentence);

say "'" . join ("', '", @words) . "'";
```

Comment: JS doesn't have lookbehinds :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that meets both your requirements:

```
/(?:\w|\b-\b)+|[^\w\s]+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cLWJ2P/1).

**Details**:

- `(?:\w|\b-\b)+` - 1 or more

  - `\w` - word char
  - `|` - or
  - `\b-\b` - a hyphen in between word characters
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]+` - 1 or more characters other than word and whitespace symbols.

See the JS demo below:

```js
var s = "I am a robot X-rrt, I am 35 and my creator is 5-MAF. Everything here is 5 times than my world5 - hurray";
console.log(s.match(/(?:\w|\b-\b)+|[^\w\s]+/g));
```